# How to cancel a recurring job in firebase job dispatcher

Tags: firebase-job-dispatcher

I have created a recurring job, I want to cancel the recurring job when some conditions met.

```
final Job.Builder builder = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setTag("myJob")
                .setService(myJobService.class)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(30, 60));
```

How can i cancel a job in firebase ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The readme on GitHub says:

> Driver is an interface that represents a component that can schedule,
>   cancel, and execute Jobs. The only bundled Driver is the
>   GooglePlayDriver, which relies on the scheduler built-in to Google
>   Play services.

So cancelling is part of the driver you are using. Inspecting [the code of the driver interface](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/jobdispatcher/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/Driver.java) there are two methods to cancel a job:

```
/**
 * Cancels the job with the provided tag and class.
 *
 * @return one of the CANCEL_RESULT_ constants.
 */
 @CancelResult
 int cancel(@NonNull String tag);

/**
 * Cancels all jobs registered with this Driver.
 *
 * @return one of the CANCEL_RESULT_ constants.
 */
 @CancelResult
 int cancelAll();
```

So in your case you have to call:

```
dispatcher.cancel("myJob");
```

or

```
dispatcher.cancelAll();
```

The dispatcher will call the corresponding method of the driver for you. If you want you can also call the methods directly on your driver `myDriver.cancelAll()` [like it is done in the sample app which comes with the GitHub project.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/testapp/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/testapp/CentralContainer.java#L109)

The chosen method will return one of the following constants:

> ```
> public static final int CANCEL_RESULT_SUCCESS = 0;
> public static final int CANCEL_RESULT_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 1;
> public static final int CANCEL_RESULT_NO_DRIVER_AVAILABLE = 2;
> ```

Comment: is there any document which mentions this ?

Comment: Not really, I found it in the sources. I fleshed out the answer a little bit more, have a look.